# DataTable BindingSource to DateGridView Filtering

Tags: c#, datagridview, bindingsource

I am trying to write some code that would write filter based off multiple conditions. In my app I have 2 date filters and 2 text filters. 
1. Is it possible to filter multiple conditions using the binding source filter property?

If not that how would I go about doing that?

My code below

```
private void btnFilter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strFilter = "";
    string strDateFilter = "Date >" + String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", dtBgnDate.Value) + " AND Date < " + String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", dtEndDate.Value);
    string strNameFilter;
    string strAcctFilter;
    strFilter = strDateFilter;

    if (!txtLName.Text.Trim().Equals(""))
    {
        strNameFilter = "LName like '%" + txtLName.Text + "%'";
        strFilter = strFilter + " AND " + strNameFilter;
    }

    if (!txtAcctNum.Text.Trim().Equals(""))
    {
        strAcctFilter = "AcctNum = " + txtAcctNum.Text;
        strFilter = strFilter + " AND " + strAcctFilter;
    }

    BindingSource bsource = new BindingSource();
    bsource.Filter = strFilter;
    bsource.DataSource = gvData.DataSource;

}
```

The code throws the following exception

```
EvaluatedException: Cannot perform '>' operation on System.DateTime and Double
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code? Does it filter at all, or throw any exceptions?

Comment: I added the exception in the original message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When filtering date values, you have to enclose them with sharp characters i.e. `#12/31/2008#`

Thus, change the following:

```
string strDateFilter = "Date > #" + String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", dtBgnDate.Value) + "# AND Date < #" + String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", dtEndDate.Value) + "#";
```

Comment: No Exception this time, but it didn't return anything.
I defined the column as follows: 
`DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataColumn col = new DataColumn("Date");
            col.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.DateTime");
            dt.Columns.Add(col);`
OR should I define the Date to be a string?